# Cascading Environment files in Angular 4

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I'm working on an angular 4 project with multiple environment files

- environment.prealpha.ts
- environment.alpha.ts
- environment.beta.ts
- environment.production.ts

There are large amounts of common lines with these files, how can I call/use a single common file and use a single specific environment file to add the unique lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we ended up doing:

commonEnvironment.ts

```
export const commonEnvironment = {
  commonVariable1 = "foo",
  commonVariable2 = "bar",
}
```

and

environment.production.ts

```
import * as common from './commonEnvironment';
export const environment = {
    ...common.commonEnvironment,
    specificVariable1 = "foo",
    specificVariable2 = "bar",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a pre build task that creates the correct environment files

Here is an idea

1. Have a environment.base.json file with common settings as a json object.

e.g.

```
{
"envName": "base",
"commonSetting": "common",
"specificSetting": ""
},
```

2. Create environment.[envName].json files, where each env file only specifies specific setting for matching environment

e.g.

```
{
"envName": "prod",
"specificSetting": "prodValue"
}
```

3. In your prebuild task, for each environment, read the base json file and the specific environment file. Create new Json object by deep merging the 2 file contents.

e.g.

```
{
"envName": "prod",
"commonSetting": "common",
"specificSetting": "prodValue"
}
```

4. In your prebuild task. for each environment, overwrite the environment.[envName].ts to generate code that assigns the environment variable from the JSON Object generated in previous step

e.g.

```
 export const environment : any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([generatedJsonObjectFromStep3]));
```